# EWS search using querystring with quotes not working for exchange 2016

Tags: query-string, exchangewebservices, exact-match

The application i work uses EWS with querystring to search for emails within a folder. When i specify  querystring like Subject:"New York", it does not return any emails which has subject "New York Jets" or "New York Mets". It will only return emails with exact match, like "New York". This works fine searching against office365, but not Exchange 2016. Does anyone know why it does not work as described in following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-perform-an-aqs-search-by-using-ews-in-exchange

My function code:

```
    private List<Item> RetrieveItems(Folder folder, string query)
    {
        const int PAGE_SIZE = 500;

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        int offset = 0;
        bool moreResults = false;

        do
        {
            ItemView view = new ItemView(PAGE_SIZE, offset);
            view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.LastModifiedTime, EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeCreated, EmailMessageSchema.Size, EmailMessageSchema.ItemClass, ItemSchema.HasAttachments);

            FindItemsResults<Item> results = null;
            Retry(() =>
            {
                results = folder.FindItems(query, view);
            });

            // Modify this to support "Collect Non-Email Data" (for non-public folder requests.)
            // Right now, we are collecting email AND non-email data unconditionally.
            items.AddRange(results);

            offset += PAGE_SIZE;
            moreResults = results.MoreAvailable;
        }
        while (moreResults);

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Does it not return anything or does it return too many results ? What CU are you running on the server ?

Comment: It does not return any result when running against exchange 2016. It works fine with office365. According to MS document on EWS and AQS queries, it should return any emails where subject contains phrase/word as long as its full word match, and not substring match.

Comment: If your not getting any results it sounds like you might have a problem with Indexing on the server as this Query will use the content indexes